# javac error: "package x does not exist" at "import x"

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile my java file 'check4PrimeTest.java' using the command prompt with the following command:

> javac -classpath .:junit.jar check4PrimeTest.java

I get the following error:

> error: package junit.framework does not exist import junit.framework.*;

I'm not sure why i get this error as i have import junit.framework.* in my program.

below is my code:

```
package check4prime;
// check4PrimeTest.java

//Imports 
import junit.framework.*;

public class check4PrimeTest extends TestCase {

    //Initialize a class to work with. 
    private check4Prime check4prime = new check4Prime();

    //constructor 
    public check4PrimeTest (String name) { 
        super(name);
    }

    //Main entry point 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting test...");
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
        System.out.println("Test finished...");
    } // end main() 

    //Test case 1 
    public void testCheckPrime_true() {
        assertTrue(check4prime.primeCheck(3));
    }

    //Test cases 2,3 
    public void testCheckPrime_false() {
        assertFalse(check4prime.primeCheck(0));
        assertFalse(check4prime.primeCheck(1000));
    }

    //Test case 7 
    public void testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_char_input() { 
        try {
            String [] args= new String[1];
            args[0]="r";
            check4prime.checkArgs(args);
            fail("Should raise an Exception.");
        } catch (Exception success) { 
            //successful test
        }
    } //end testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_char_input() 

    //Test case 5 
    public void testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_above_upper_bound() {
        try { 
            String [] args= new String[1];
            args[0]="10001";
            check4prime.checkArgs(args);
            fail("Should raise an Exception.");
        } catch (Exception success) { 
            //successful test
        }
    } // end testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_upper_bound() 

    //Test case 4 
    public void testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_neg_input() {
        try { 
            String [] args= new String[1];
            args[0]="-1";
            check4prime.checkArgs(args);
            fail("Should raise an Exception.");
        } catch (Exception success) { 
            //successful test
        }
    } // end testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_neg_input()

    //Test case 6
    public void testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_2_inputs() {
        try { 
            String [] args= new String[2];
            args[0]="5";
            args[1]="99";
            check4prime.checkArgs(args);
            fail("Should raise an Exception.");
         } catch (Exception success) {
            //successful test 
         } 
    } // end testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_2_inputs 

    //Test case 8 
    public void testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_0_inputs() {
        try { 
            String [] args= new String[0];
            check4prime.checkArgs(args);
            fail("Should raise an Exception.");
        } catch (Exception success) { 
            //successful test
        } 
    } // end testCheck4Prime_checkArgs_0_inputs 

    //JUnit required method. 
    public static Test suite() { 
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(check4PrimeTest.class);
        return suite;
    } //end suite() 

} //end check4PrimeTest
```

Comment: how would it look after i add it?

Comment: That depends on where your junit files are. I'll see if I can't dig up some syntax.

Comment: If you're working in eclipse, Right click on project > build path> configure build path> external library> find it and click ok.

--that was from memory so its probably not 100%

Comment: @weberc2 am i supposed to put junit4.10 in jdk1.7.0_03/bin folder?

Comment: @JonSnow if you've resolved your issue, please select mark the appropriate answer or add your own.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting this error because you're trying to import a package without telling your system where the package is located. Here are instructions on telling your system where the package is located:

> Your javac target doesn't specify anything apart from the source and
>   target directory - it doesn't add any classpath entries; you'll need
>   to add an entry for the appropriate JUnit jar file. See the javac task
>   documentation for more details. You may want to specify the path to
>   JUnit as a classpath attribute, a nested element, or a reference to a
>   path declared elsewhere.

- [javac task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Source: [problem running JUnit tests with Ant in Eclipse. Beginner question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547439/problem-running-junit-tests-with-ant-in-eclipse-beginner-question)

`prompt> javac -classpath .;$JUNIT_HOME\junit4.x.x.jar test.java`

**EDIT: JUNIT INSTALLATION (from [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#started)):**

> Windows
>
> To install JUnit on Windows, follow these steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Unzip the junit.zip distribution file to a directory referred to as %JUNIT_HOME%.
>
> 2. Add JUnit to the classpath (type the following into a command line shell): `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit.jar`
> ```
>
> Unix (bash)
>
> To install JUnit on Unix, follow these steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Unzip the junit.zip distribution file to a directory referred to as $JUNIT_HOME.
>
> 2. Add JUnit to the classpath (type the following into terminal):
>
> `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/junit.jar`
> ```

Comment: how do i specify the path to JUnit as a classpath?

Comment: @cobolstinks the junit download file 'junit4.10' am i supposed to put that in jdk1.7.0_03/bin folder? of my directory?

Comment: @JonSnow, it shouldn't matter where you install junit4.10; however, you have to tell your system where to look for it. You do that with environment variables as described in my most recent edit (under "JUNIT INSTALLATION". Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: i followed you're instructions on installing Junit on windows.
1. i created a dir named %JUNIT_HOME% in my 'program files(x86)' and extracted the junit4.10 foldier into it
2. added the junit classpath from the cmd with set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit.jar which worked! but when i tried compiling the 'check4PrimeTest.java' file from the desktop it showed up with the same error regarding not having 'error: package junit.framework does not exist import junit.framework.*;'

Used the following command for compile: 
C:\Users\J\Desktop>javac -classpath .:junit.jar check4PrimeTest.java

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement tells the compiler that you need an artifact, in this case you're telling the compiler you need to use junit. But declaring you're using it and providing it to the JVM are different things.  You need to make sure your junit jar file is on your classpath.

**EDIT:**  By the way using an IDE will be a time saver for you.  I realize eclipse can be intimidating, but I would recommend starting to use it.  Unless you're more of a command line type of person, but even then if you're doing anything serious you should use an IDE IMO.

Comment: Personally, I believe it's a good idea to understand how to do it manually before relying on an IDE, but a good IDE will definitely increase your efficiency (I recommend NetBeans as it's not nearly as buggy as eclipse IMHO). To each his own, however.

Comment: yeap kinda like doing arithmetic manually vs using a calculator. Probably why i'm not that smart and rely on a calculator :).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are importing a package or using a jar file which it is unable to locate.

You should check your environment variables for classpath variable.
Add the path of your jar file or your package to the classpath variable.
Also, add your java file's class file path to the classpath variable if it shows the error "cannot load class, main file not found"

Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 9 or later with JUnit 5 or later, then it is possible that the JUnit package is defined in a module, and you may need to use `--module-path` to point to the directory which contains the module/Modular JAR.

Comment: This was my case

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ***On windows*** machine, I just 
replaced colon :  with semicolon ;
and it worked !

> javac -cp .:./abc.jar:./def.jar Practice.java
>   Practice.java:2: error: package com.coding.javapractice does not exist

After replacing : with ;

> javac -cp .;./abc.jar;./def.jar Practice.java

Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer here, in case it helps someone. If trying to import multiple jars, you can use the `*` wildcard. The command that worked for me (windows 10, java 17) is:

```
javac -cp .;* Canvas
```